# URL and Silverlight Deep linking

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, url, deep-linking

I've a question about Silverlight:

I tested a little bit Flex before, but I remember that there was a way to have URLs changing depending of the view on which we are. If I remember this good, this is called "Deep linking" in Flex.

Like this we can easily:

- Copy paste the current URL and send it to someone.
- Send email which goes on specific view of our application.
- Do back-next operation in-browser.

Is there something like this with Silverlight? (I've a `telerik` license so if you know something in their component, I'm interested too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Silverlight Navigation Framework](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx)

Comment: Another useful google search term for silverlight navigation is "silverlight frame navigation"